# Using XBee and OLED screens with Timer Interrupts

Tags: arduino-mega, xbee, interrupt, timers

I have an Arduino board with a sensor, an OLED screen and an XBee module. I've setup the timer interrupts in timer1 to sample the sensor every one second. 
I've done the following:

- tried to update the OLED screen with the reading and it works.
- tried sending the reading from inside loop over XBee and it works.
- tried doing both of the above and the Arduino seems to shut down after a bit.
- tried sending the reading from inside the timer interrupt handler and it doesn't work.

Are there limitations on what interrupt handlers can do that I'm not aware of? (Other than using time delays)

**Source code**

```
#include <XBee.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

XBee xbee = XBee();
ZBRxResponse response = ZBRxResponse();
ZBTxRequest sensorml_level_0_zbTx = ZBTxRequest(addr64, sensorml_payload_level_0,sizeof(sensorml_payload_level_0));
ZBTxRequest keepalive_level_0_zbTx = ZBTxRequest(addr64, keepalive_payload_level_0,sizeof(keepalive_payload_level_0));

union u_tag {
   uint8_t b[4];
   float fval;
} 
u;

void setup() {
   display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   xbee.setSerial(Serial);
   noInterrupts();
   TCCR1A = 0;
   TCCR1B = 0;
   TCNT1  = 0;
   OCR1A = 62500;
   TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
   TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);
   TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10);
   TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
   interrupts();
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
   reading =  analogRead(SENSORPIN);
   reading = (1023 / reading)  - 1;
   reading = SERIESRESISTOR / reading;
   reading = -0.15784 * reading + 305.17;
   sendObservation(reading,00);
}

void sendObservation(float value, int id){
   char idBuffer[] = "00";
   sprintf(idBuffer,"%02d",id);
   uint8_t frame[] = {'0','1','|','0','0','#','0','0','0','0'};
   frame[3] = idBuffer[0];
   frame[4] = idBuffer[1];
   u.fval = value;
   for (int i=6;i<10;i++){
      frame[i]=u.b[i-6];
   }
   ZBTxRequest request = ZBTxRequest(addr64, frame, sizeof(frame));
   xbee.send(request);
}
```

I skipped most variable declarations to keep the code short.

Comment: Just so you know, cross posting is not allowed.

Comment: Should I remove it then? Why is it not?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/238586. The Stack Overflow one should be closed soon, so don't remove this one.

Comment: You say the arduino shuts down after a bit; How long is that? does anything get through before it stops responding? also, what is happening in loop during all this?

Comment: @BrettM I can't say for sure how long it takes. I will be able to on monday though. So I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `send()` is blocking.

`XBee::send()` calls `_serial->flush()` (see [code](https://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino/source/browse/XBee.cpp#1461)). `Serial.write()` buffers data to be written, sets `transmitting = true`, clears `TXC0` and enables the USART data register empty (DRE) interrupt. Bytes will be sent out when the DRE interrupt triggers. However, since you are currently in interrupt context, this will not happen until your ISR returns. `flush()` spins until `TXC0` is set, but since the DRE interrupt never triggers, it spins infinitely. I am basing this on [this code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L455).

Comment: Yes, serial doesn't work in interrupts.